# when update Image fields, then initial data does not work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

here is the model

```
class UserInfoModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, unique=True)
    web_site = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    biography = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(
       upload_to=upload_location,
       null=True,
       blank=True,
       height_field='height_field',
       width_field='width_field',
   )
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

here is the views

```
# my info
try:
    my_image = cache.get(request.user, None)
    if not my_image:
        my_image = UserInfoModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
        cache.set(request.user, my_image, None)
except:
    my_image = None
try:
    info_user = my_image
    initial_data = {
        'web_site': info_user.web_site,
        'biography': info_user.biography,
    }
    info = UserInfoForm(request.POST or None, instance=info_user, initial=initial_data)
except:
    info = UserInfoForm(request.POST or None)

if info.is_valid():
    new_info = info.save(commit=False)
    new_info.user = request.user
    new_info.save()
    return redirect('/index/')
```

above the code, if there is initial datas then I showed the datas in page then we can make changes if we want, and the initial data works very fine

```
# my info
try:
    my_image = cache.get(request.user, None)
    if not my_image:
        my_image = UserInfoModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
        cache.set(request.user, my_image, None)
except:
    my_image = None
try:
    info_user = my_image
    initial_data = {
        'web_site': info_user.web_site,
        'biography': info_user.biography,
    }
    user_form = UserInfoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=info_user, initial=initial_data)
except:
    user_form = UserInfoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

if user_form.is_valid():
    form = user_form.save(commit=False)
    form.user = request.user
    form.save()
    return redirect('/'+str(request.user.username)+'/')
```

but above the code, if I save any images in model then all type textfields are gone

in model I have 1 image field 2 text field, but text fields and image field stays in different page but it does not make trouble, because textfields and image field is null true blank true, in text field's page if I save then everything is saved even if image field has image then images are not gone, but in images field's page if I save image then all text fields are gone, why it is happening

*=========== SOLUTION =============*

Okey This is so confusing me because every save methods, update methods works that way, but if you have one model and this model has images and texts then if you want to update images and texts from separate pages, the Problem comes from inside HTML document, because when you put the enctype='multipart/data' then html document does not render any of initial datas which we specify inside the views, but if you update your texts in other page everything is okey, just works fine. So the solution is if you have like that project then use separate models for this, that will work, have a good day.

Comment: Try add initial argument to UserInfoForm: `user_form = UserInfoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=info_user, initial=initial_data)`

Comment: I am sorry i just forget to add it into sample code, but I did of course, nothing happens also

Comment: so you have two pages, one pages with text fields, another with image field? are these pages rendered as separate forms? can you provide more code?

Comment: Yes i have two pages, the model is same, in the model 3 fields, two of them textfield one is image field, im views i defined two function, in one function rendered only text fields but it works fine it just saves nothing goes wrong, in other function, uses same model and i use it just for saving image, but image is saved by the way all text datas are gone